Generalization of the fact that for $f: S^1 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ continuous, $\exists x \in S^1 : f(x) = f(-x)$
While going through James Munkres' book on topology I came across the following problem:

Let $f: S^1 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ a continuous function. Show that there exists a point $x \in S^1$ st. $f(x)=f(-x)$

And after proving it and playing around a big with the statement, I believe that my proof could be generalized to the following statement:

Claim. Let $G$ be a topological group and let $X$ be a connected subspace such that $\forall x\in G: x \in X \implies x^{-1} \in X$ where $x^{-1}$ is the inverse element of $x$ wrt to the group operation. Then for $f: X \rightarrow \Bbb R$ continuous, there exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x) = f(x^{-1})$.

Proof. Assume that $\forall x \in X: f(x) \neq f(x^{-1})$, then the function $g(x) := {f(x) - f(x^{-1}) \over |f(x) - f(x^{-1})|}$ is a continuous map from $X$ to $\{-1, 1\}$ where the latter is a discrete subspace in $\Bbb R$. But then, since the space $X$ is connected, it follows that $g$ must be a constant function. So let w.l.o.g $g \equiv 1$. Then it follows that $\forall x \in X: f(x)-f(x^{-1}) = |f(x)-f(x^{-1})| \geq 0$, which gives us that: $$f(x)-f(x^{-1}) \geq 0 \implies f(x)\ge f(x^{-1})$$
But then, by uniqueness of the inverse element, we find that
$$f(x)\geq f(x^{-1}) \geq f\left(\left(x^{-1}\right)^{-1}\right) = f(x) \implies f(x) = f(x^{-1})$$
Which is a contradiction. $\square$
Question. Are there any leaps in my logic regarding this generalization? In particular, is my reasoning behind the contradiction using $f(x) \ge f(x^{-1})$ valid? I'd also like to know, can one weaken the conditions on $X$ even more? And what about the image of $f$? As far as I know I'm only using the fact that $\Bbb R$ is an ordered field here, am I wrong?

Hint: Look for counter-examples for which there exists an injective continuous map to $\mathbb R$ (they are easy to find).

@MoisheKohan Sorry I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. Which question are you responding to with this?

I am commenting on the claim that you are trying to prove ("Let $G$ be a topological group...").

Go through every step of your proof and check if it works in this example.

@MoisheKohan My bad, the example I just gave ($id: \Bbb R \setminus {0} \rightarrow \Bbb R$) and deleted again does not fulfill the hypothesis, since $X = \Bbb R \setminus {0}$ is not connected. I will try to find a different counter-example

@MoisheKohan Could you tell me what counter example you have in mind? Or at least which space $X$ you are using. I cannot seem to come up with anything.

I was assuming that you are excluding the case $x=1$.

@MoisheKohan I am not. Because the statement is trivial if the neutral element is included, I weakened the assumptions to any "symmteric" subspace of a topological group.

Your argument is correct, here is a more approriate generalization, since you never really need the group operation but only the inversion:

Let $X$ be a connected topological space equipped with a continuous involution, i.e. $\iota:X\rightarrow X$ such that $\iota\circ\iota=\text{id}_X$, and $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb R$, then there exists $x\in X$, such that $f(x)=f(\iota(x))$.

We can even further generalize to:

Let $X$ be connected equipped with continuous action $\iota: X\rightarrow X$, and $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb R$. If $\forall x, f(x)\not=f(\iota(x))$, then $\iota$ has no finite orbit (i.e. $\forall n\ge 1, \iota^n$ has no fixed point).

A slightly different proof: Note that $g(x):=f(x)-f(\iota(x))$ is a function from $X$ to $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, and since $X$ is connected, $g(X)\subset(-\infty, 0)$ or $g(X)\subset(0, \infty)$. In the first case, $f(x)<f(\iota(x))$ for all $x$, hence $x, \iota(x), \iota^2(x), \cdots$ are all distinct, as the sequence $f(x), f(\iota(x)), f(\iota^2(x)), \cdots$ is strictly increasing. The second case can be handled similarly.

Interesting, thank you very much! Is there any further relaxations we can put on the range of $f$ in this generalization?

@clorx this is a topological result, so we have to assume some continuity. One possible direction of generalization is to consider (partially) ordered sets instead of $\mathbb R$ as a topological space. I'm sure there are some results in semigroup dynamical systems.
